# opensips running but not listen the port 5070

Tags: opensips

I set up the opensips server but it does not listen to the set port after startup.

My environment is as follows:
centos 8
opensips 3.1.5
opensips-cp 8.3.1
mysql 8.0.26
SELinux disable
firewall has opened the corresponding port

firewall setting:

```
public (active)
  target: default
  icmp-block-inversion: no
  interfaces: ens192
  sources:
  services: cockpit dhcpv6-client ssh
  ports: 3306/tcp 5060/udp 8080/tcp 5070/udp
  protocols:
  forward: no
  masquerade: no
  forward-ports:
  source-ports:
  icmp-blocks:
  rich rules:
```

opensips.log:

```
[root@SipServer opensips-cp]# tail -f /var/log/opensips.log
Jun 16 03:50:29 [15088] DBG:core:db_do_init: connection 0x7f95f19ad0a0 found in pool as 0x7f95f19ac9d8
Jun 16 03:50:29 [15090] DBG:core:send_status_code: sent code 0 (1 byte)
Jun 16 03:50:29 [15088] DBG:core:init_mod_child: type=CHILD, rank=3, module=auth_db
Jun 16 03:50:29 [15080] DBG:core:wait_status_code: read code 0 (1 byte)
Jun 16 03:50:29 [15088] DBG:core:db_do_init: connection 0x7f95f19ad210 found in pool as 0x7f95f19ac9d8
Jun 16 03:50:29 [15088] DBG:core:init_mod_child: type=CHILD, rank=3, module=dialog
Jun 16 03:50:29 [15088] DBG:core:db_do_init: connection 0x7f95f19ad150 found in pool as 0x7f95f19ac9d8
Jun 16 03:50:29 [15088] DBG:core:send_status_code: sent code 0 (1 byte)
Jun 16 03:50:29 [15080] DBG:core:wait_status_code: read code 0 (1 byte)
Jun 16 03:50:29 [15080] INFO:core:daemonize: pre-daemon process exiting with 0
```

opensips process is running:

```
[root@SipServer opensips-cp]# ps aux | grep opensips
root       15082  0.0  0.3 131144 14644 ?        S    03:50   0:00 opensips start -f /usr/local/etc/opensips/opensips.cfg
root       15083  0.0  0.1 131144  5804 ?        S    03:50   0:00 opensips start -f /usr/local/etc/opensips/opensips.cfg
root       15084  0.0  0.0 131144  3080 ?        S    03:50   0:02 opensips start -f /usr/local/etc/opensips/opensips.cfg
root       15085  0.0  0.0 131144  3144 ?        S    03:50   0:01 opensips start -f /usr/local/etc/opensips/opensips.cfg
root       15086  0.0  0.1 131144  6240 ?        S    03:50   0:00 opensips start -f /usr/local/etc/opensips/opensips.cfg
root       15087  0.0  0.1 131144  6084 ?        S    03:50   0:00 opensips start -f /usr/local/etc/opensips/opensips.cfg
root       15088  0.0  0.1 131144  6088 ?        S    03:50   0:00 opensips start -f /usr/local/etc/opensips/opensips.cfg
root       15089  0.0  0.1 131144  6084 ?        S    03:50   0:00 opensips start -f /usr/local/etc/opensips/opensips.cfg
root       15090  0.0  0.1 131144  6024 ?        S    03:50   0:00 opensips start -f /usr/local/etc/opensips/opensips.cfg
root       15716  0.0  0.0  12136  1160 pts/0    S+   04:34   0:00 grep --color=auto opensips
```

opensips not listenning port 5070

```
[root@SipServer opensips-cp]# netstat -tulpn
Active Internet connections (only servers)
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address           Foreign Address         State       PID/Program name    
tcp        0      0 192.168.122.1:53        0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      3162/dnsmasq        
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:22              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      1230/sshd          
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:631           0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      1235/cupsd          
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:6010          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      3512/sshd: root@pts
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:111             0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      1/systemd          
tcp6       0      0 :::22                   :::*                    LISTEN      1230/sshd          
tcp6       0      0 ::1:631                 :::*                    LISTEN      1235/cupsd          
tcp6       0      0 ::1:6010                :::*                    LISTEN      3512/sshd: root@pts
tcp6       0      0 :::443                  :::*                    LISTEN      14536/httpd        
tcp6       0      0 :::33060                :::*                    LISTEN      1354/mysqld        
tcp6       0      0 :::3306                 :::*                    LISTEN      1354/mysqld        
tcp6       0      0 :::111                  :::*                    LISTEN      1/systemd          
tcp6       0      0 :::8080                 :::*                    LISTEN      14536/httpd        
udp        0      0 127.0.0.1:323           0.0.0.0:*                           1091/chronyd        
udp        0      0 0.0.0.0:5070            0.0.0.0:*                           15082/opensips      
udp        0      0 0.0.0.0:5353            0.0.0.0:*                           1081/avahi-daemon:  
udp        0      0 0.0.0.0:59061           0.0.0.0:*                           1081/avahi-daemon:  
udp        0      0 192.168.122.1:53        0.0.0.0:*                           3162/dnsmasq        
udp        0      0 0.0.0.0:67              0.0.0.0:*                           3162/dnsmasq        
udp        0      0 0.0.0.0:111             0.0.0.0:*                           1/systemd          
udp6       0      0 ::1:323                 :::*                                1091/chronyd        
udp6       0      0 :::50306                :::*                                1081/avahi-daemon:  
udp6       0      0 :::5353                 :::*                                1081/avahi-daemon:  
udp6       0      0 :::111                  :::*                                1/systemd
```

opensips.cfg

```
####### Global Parameters #########

/* uncomment the following lines to enable debugging */
#debug_mode=yes

log_level=4
xlog_level=4
log_stderror=yes
log_facility=LOG_LOCAL0

udp_workers=4

/* uncomment the next line to enable the auto temporary blacklisting of
   not available destinations (default disabled) */
#disable_dns_blacklist=no

/* uncomment the next line to enable IPv6 lookup after IPv4 dns
   lookup failures (default disabled) */
#dns_try_ipv6=yes


# socket=udp:127.0.0.1:5060   # CUSTOMIZE ME
auto_aliases=no

socket=udp:0.0.0.0:5070
#alias=udp:0.0.0.0:5070

db_default_url="mysql://opensips:opensipsrw@localhost:3306/opensips"
```

There are no errors, so I don’t know how to check the problem. Have any of you experienced similar situations?